# Does a dynamically-created View inherit theme attributes?

Tags: android

In Android, say if I dynamically create a TextView with:

```
TextView view = new TextView();
```

and add it to the root view of an activity. Does this view inherit theme properties such as text color?

If so when does this happen? At the time of its creation or the time of adding the view?

Comment: it's `new TextView(context)` and the `Context` carries those information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zapl said, use `new TextView(context)`. Also, make sure you use the activity context to inherit the activity's theme/style instead of application context.

Comment: Thank you! There are multiple constructors so I just omitted the parameters. But all of them have a `Context` parameter.